# How to access pdf file from a shared folder using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, shared-directory

I have one folder "**PDFStore**" shared with **EVERYONE** in my machine.

The code base is present in another remote machine.

I want to access the PDF file present within the folder **PDFStore** through **Javascript** from the remote machine.

so that i can open the PDF file in a new tab using **Window.open()** to fulfill my requirement.

When giving the path as the network path of the file, it is showing the error **"Access denied"**.

Please suggest how can i access the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you can do this by providing the ip address of your local machine.

You may try with the following path

`"your_ip/the_alias_name_of_the_application/the_mapping_shared_folder"`

The alias name would do the trick if hosted in IIS server.

Comment: Thanks Ashis, i have tried with the above path format and it works.